# Adding a trailing slash on wordpress

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, adsense

I want to add a trailing slash in my wordpress blog. It's in the generic URL form and I would like to keep it that way.
http://myblog.com/?p=666

I've searched a lot before posting but didn't find an example to this specific case.
This is a production site so I can't afford to experiment with regex.

The reason behind it is to overcome strange Adsense glitch not showing ads on random pages. Adding anything at the end of the url make the ads to show again. This is not "page content" issue if anyone concerned...

Thanks,
Vadim

Comment: Huh? You mean like `?p=666/`? Why? The `?` indicates the query string, it doesn't need a trailing slash...

Comment: Yes. There is some strange adsense problem on some random posts. appending a trailing slash(or anything) makes the ads work.

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own question...

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^p=([0-9]*)$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://mydomain.site/?p=%1/ [R=302,L]
```

Now my ads are back!